# Restart Animation After It Ran Through

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have 3 arrow icons in my Call To Action that one by one fade in from opacity 0 to opacity 1. Everything works just fine but what I want to do is once all 3 of the arrow icons have faded in, I want to set all of them back to opacity 0 and restart the one by one loop. I am stuck on how to restart it. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code I have so far to get the animation to work once.

```
$('.cta-icon').each(function(i, el) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  $(el).css('opacity', '1');
 }, i * 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a setInterval, and using fadeIn and fadeOut chained together.

```
var interval;
$('.cta-icon').each(function(i, el) {
 interval = setInterval(function() {
  $(el).fadeIn(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
 }, 1000);
});
...
clearInterval(interval) //stop the interval
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to animate the buttons, why don't you do that via CSS? No JS required for this:

```
.blink_me {
  animation: blinker 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {  
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
}
```

Would blend the element each second in and out. If you prefer the jQuery way, you could go for `animate`.

```
 $().ready(function() {
   var _fadeIn = function() {
      $(this).animate({'opacity':1},1000, _fadeOut );
   },
  _fadeOut = function() {
      $(this).animate({'opacity':0},1000, _fadeIn );
   };
  $('.cta-icon').each(_fadeOut);
 });
```

You find a small example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWQRqx).